# how to create various background images (div)

Tags: php, html, css, ckeditor

I've got new articles in my DB with a (title, subtitle, date and an image) I'm trying to display like the right [card here](https://codepen.io/choogoor/pen/YWBxAg)  I've tried it in CSS like the example but that will only work with one image. I'm displaying three of them in on the same page.

There's also another issue the images are added through `ckfinder` which always contains a P tag and `img` tag.

so I've tried to use an `img` tag as background but the image comes out on the right side.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if ($row['aafbeelding'] == ''){
         echo "<img src='images/tumbnail.png' class='w3-third'>";
      } else {
         echo $row["aafbeelding"];
      }
   echo "<div class='wrapper'><div class='header'><div class='date'><span class='day'>12</span><span class='month'>Aug</span><span class='year'>2016</span></div></div><div class='data'><div class='menu-content'>";
   echo "<h1 class='title'><a href='#'>".$row["titel"]."</a></h1>";
   echo "<p class='text'>".$row["subtitel"]."</p>";
   echo "<a href='#letstenuujts' class='button'>Laes meer</a>";
   echo "</div></div></div></div>";
}
```

`$row["aafbeelding"]` is for example:

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://localhost/tuinhagedisse/images/Sponsors/Hermus.png" style="height:213px; width:480px" /></p>
```

CSS =

```
.example-2 img {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
}
```

How can I make sure the image contains the background like on the example but then dynamic?

also, I've got a solution in my mind but then I need CKfinder to only upload the path to the server so without the p and `img` tag height etc.. is that possible?

Comment: Why are you using CKEditor for this? Seems like a normal image uploader endpoint would work better, since you only want the image url.

Comment: Then people can also choose from images already on the server and delete them in case needed. Which is not possible with an image uploader correct? I’m new to building sites which can be changed by end users so i dont have much knowledge of editors and uploaders. But will check this out later today.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do with CSS only.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<div class='example'>";
      if ($row['aafbeelding'] == ''){
         echo "<img src='images/tumbnail.png' class='w3-third'>";
      } else {
         echo $row["aafbeelding"];
      }
      echo "<div class='wrapper'><div class='header'><div class='date'><span class='day'>12</span><span class='month'>Aug</span><span class='year'>2016</span></div></div><div class='data'><div class='menu-content'>";
      echo "<h1 class='title'><a href='#'>".$row["titel"]."</a></h1>";
      echo "<p class='text'>".$row["subtitel"]."</p>";
      echo "<a href='#letstenuujts' class='button'>Laes meer</a>";
      echo "</div></div></div></div>";
   }
}

.example {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
}

.example > p {
  display: inline;
}

.example img {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 213px;
  width: 480px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

[JSFiddle for static example](https://jsfiddle.net/thedutchess/xz38kt4m/)

Comment: nou de hoogte en breedte is slechts ter voorbeeld dit doet CKfinder zelf aangezien dit de orginele afmetingen zijn. de afmetingen van de wrapper zijn echter responsive waardoor een vaste waarde zich niet leent. de echte afmetingen zijn als in het voorbeeld. in het voorbeeld gebruiken ze div style background image maar door CKfinder lukt dit niet gezien de link als <p><img> verpakt wordt. of de output moet gestript worden of de input maar ik heb geen idee hoe dat werkt.